# When creating excel with Python xlsxwriter, format only "takes" after cell is double clicked

Tags: python, excel, format, xlsxwriter

I created a script that produces a data frame that I would like to put into an excel document. In the below code I am setting what I believe is the correct parameters for setting up the format of each column.

Once the excel has been produced, the format is not correct in each cell.
The format only becomes correct once I double click the cell.

Checking the format of the excel document shows that for each row my format was set by the code but not displayed.

Thanks in advance for any advice that might solve this.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Apr 30 10:28:45 2019

@author: ny
"""
import logging
import sys
import pyodbc           # Database connector
import pandas as pd     # Data frames 
import datetime         # Dates and time 
from datetime import timedelta 

import numpy as np 



test =  {'col1':['USD'],
         'col2':['USD Fed'],
         'col3':['2019-01-04 15:15:00'],
         'col4':['2019-01-04 15:24:59.999'],
         'col5':['1.13564'],
         'col6':['1.13528'],
         'col7':['1.13845'],
         'col8':['1.137'],
         'col9':['0.002474375682434556'],
         'col10':['0.0015150447466703754'],
         'col11':['-28.10'],
         'col12':['-17.20']}
testdf = pd.DataFrame(data=test)

#results = results.sort_values(by=['TimeStart'], ascending=False)
#Excel

#results = results.applymap(str)

outputString = 'test' + "MarketMovement.xlsx"
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(outputString, engine = 'xlsxwriter')



testdf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name ='Events',index = False)
resultsLn = len(testdf)
Clength = 'A1:L'+str(resultsLn+1)
workbook = writer.book
num_fmt =  workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00000'})
day_fmt     =  workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'})                                 

worksheet = writer.sheets['Events']    


worksheet.add_table(Clength, {'columns': [
  {'header': 'titleCurrency'}#a
 ,{'header': 'Event'}#a
 ,{'header': 'TimeStart'}#a
 ,{'header': 'TimeEnd'}#b
 ,{'header': 't1HighRate'}#c
 ,{'header': 't1LowRate'}#d
 ,{'header': 't10HighRate'}#e
 ,{'header': 't10LowRate'}#f
 ,{'header': 'PercentHighChange'}#g
 ,{'header': 'PercentLowChange'}#h
 ,{'header': 'changeHighPips'}#i
 ,{'header': 'changeLowPips'}#j
 ],
                                   'autofilter': True,
                                   'total_row': False,
                                   'style': 'Table Style Medium 2'})   



worksheet.set_column('A:A', 20)  
worksheet.set_column('B:B', 20)     
worksheet.set_column('C:C', 20, day_fmt)    
worksheet.set_column('D:D',20, day_fmt)
worksheet.set_column('E:E',25, num_fmt)
worksheet.set_column('F:F',25, num_fmt)
worksheet.set_column('G:G',25, num_fmt)
worksheet.set_column('H:H',25, num_fmt)
worksheet.set_column('I:I',25, num_fmt)
worksheet.set_column('J:J',25, num_fmt)
worksheet.set_column('K:K',25, num_fmt)
worksheet.set_column('L:L',25, num_fmt)

writer.save()
writer.close()   

#Clear all kernel after finished 
# import IPython
# app = IPython.Application.instance()
# app.kernel.do_shutdown(True)
```

Comment: It isn't possible to say what the issue is without a complete working example. However, the syntax of `set_column()` isn't correct. It takes a column, not cell, range. See the [set_column() docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-set-column). I don't know if it is the issue but you should fix it at least.

Comment: Thanks, Will fix that and get back. What more detail could I provide that would be helpful?

Comment: Format is now ```worksheet.set_column('A:A', 20)``` Did not change anything.

Comment: I added a completed working example

Comment: Thanks for the example. The data isn't being formatted because it is being written as strings and Excel only applies numeric formatting to numbers. So you will need to convert your number and date data to numbers and dates (using datetime.py).

Comment: you sir are a gentlemen and a scholar. Thanks for the help! Any way you can post this as the answer and ill check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is that I need to make sure the data type matches up completely.
Need to use proper datetime format for python and numeric for the numbers.
Solution was provided by  jmcnamara.

Comment: This is not true at all, excel have his own mind